# Error: Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components, when React component name has underscore?

Tags: reactjs, vite

#### question

When I use `TestRcomp3` // no underscore => no error

When I use `Test_Rcomp3` // with underscore => error above -- Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components.

Why?

(Underscore should be allowed in React Component naming?)

(I dont want to unnecessarily move each React Component to its own file, that makes the project messy.)

```
import React from 'react';

// Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components. Move your component(s) to a separate file.eslint(react-refresh/only-export-components)
const TestRcomp1: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>1111</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// export const TestRcomp3: React.FC = () => { // no underscore => no error
export const Test_Rcomp3: React.FC = () => { // with underscore => error above
  return (
    <div>
      <div>3333</div>
      <TestRcomp1 />
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### environment

Using Vite + React

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
```